# Dynamic Page for Search Engines

Tags: dynamic, seo

if i am creating pages Dynamically with PHP and my URL, Title Tag, Meta Tags, Body Contents & Text all are for one single entity\tag\keyword and all the generated data is legit... will the search engines consider it as a separate page present in my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would depend on how unique the content is, you might end up seeing this message in the results pages, showing that the content on those pages is similar and *not* unique.

> In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the [X] already displayed.
>   If you like, you can repeat the search with the omitted results included.

If you have to rationalize the legitimacy of something SEO-related, or you're doing it for the sake of the crawlers and not your users, then, it *might* not be seen as legit...